# SharePoint custom display form yes/no checkboxes

Tags: sharepoint

We have a custom list with custom New, Edit, and Display forms.  Some of the fields in the Edit form are Read Only and thus I used  which works great.  The problem is that any yes/no columns display with a "1" or "0" instead of the checkbox.  Is there anyway either in the xsl tag or using JavaScript/JQuery to display a checkbox?  I was hoping to avoid using calculated columns so that I didn't have to create one for each yes/no column.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an XSLT conditional such as:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@MyCheckbox = '1'">Yes</xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```